# How do you manually install the eclipse-CDT plugin from an archive/zip on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I have successfully installed Eclipse 3.5 and Java 1.5. I would like to install CDT without using Eclipse's "install new features" (nor can i use the Eclipse-CDT installer) option because this computer is offline.

What I did:

1. I downloaded the [archive of cdt from CDT's official download page](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/galileo/).
2. I used file-roller to unzip everything into the eclipse folder (the plugins/features now have a ton of *cdt* files)
3. I started Eclipse with -clean
4. When I clicked the New Project. The GUI dialog box did not show C/C++... and there was no C/C++ perspective

Eclipse appeared to have ignored my unzipping CDT.

Have you ever installed CDT using the offline archive?

What steps have I missed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On eclipse 3.5, instead of unzipping onto the eclipse folder, try "Help" -> "Install New Software..." then "Add" and instead of typing an update site, choose "Archive". Then follow the instructions.

Comment: have you tried this and seen it work? Where is this mentioned in Eclipse documentation?

Comment: Jungle's right. See the instructions on one of the nightly builds:  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/

Comment: You can also drop plugins and features into the 'dropins' folder as an alternative to installing using the UI. P2 will reconcile these plugins into Eclipse on startup (which may go wrong...). See also: http://dsdp.eclipse.org/help/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html and http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins

Answer (score 1):

That should have worked. Unzipping on top of the distribution is a more-or-less officially supported installation path. You seem to have confirmed that the files ended up in the right place.

It could be that the cdt version doesn't match the Eclipse version.

Try `Help -> Software Updates...`, and see if you can turn a feature on.

Try `Help -> About Eclipse Platform`, then the various info buttons in there, and see if you can find an error or a list of disabled features. Check the enabled list too...

As a last resort you could try removing the contents of the `configuration` directory at the eclipse root. Back it up first, and don't delete `config.ini`. Restart with `-clean`.

Comment: No this is no longer true.  This used to be the case with the old Update Manager. Now that Eclipse uses the p2 provisioning engine, unzipping the plugins / features directly into the install is not at all recommended.

Comment: I note you're using an Eclipse before p2 was introduced in 3.4 - as 'Software Updates...' has been replaced by 'Install New Software...'

Answer (score -3):

On eclipse HELIOS I just put the downloaded .JAR file in `C:\eclipse-jee-helios-win32\plugins` and restart eclipse.

Usually the plugin will show up in menu "New/Other" in workspace window.

Comment: "How do you [...] install [...] on ubuntu"