# Install Sconsolidator Eclipse CDT plugin offliine?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, scons

I am using Eclipse CDT 4.6.3 on an offline Linux machine, and need to install SConsolidator.  I've downloaded the archive from [GitHub](https://github.com/IFS-HSR/SConsolidator).

In Eclipse, I go to help > install new software, and have tried to add SConsolidator both as an archive with the zip folder, and local with the folder unzipped. In both cases, I get the error "could not find file".  I've tried storing the zip file both in the workspace and out.

How can I install SConsolidator for Eclipse?

edit:

Attempting to use Maven to build the files from GitHub, still running into problems though

Comment: You haven't specified exactly what you are downloading? The release zip here https://github.com/IFS-HSR/SConsolidator/releases is the source files which is not installable, it needs to be built first. I don't see any other zip files. Additionally, the shield on their readme says they are in build error. Try getting in touch with the code owners http://ifs.hsr.ch

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390937/how-do-you-manually-install-the-eclipse-cdt-plugin-from-an-archive-zip-on-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @JonahGraham, I see I was downloading the files that were not installable.  I got in touch with the people on GitHub, who recommended that I try to use Maven to build the installable files (which I'm also not currently having luck with, but going to continue to try)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Help > Install New Software...* requires an update site. Get a local copy of the update site by running following command from the command line within the Eclipse (at least the [Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.7-201706120950/#PlatformRuntime)) installation directory (adjust *-destination* to your needs):

```
eclipsec -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication -source http://www.sconsolidator.com/update -destination file:C:/SConsUpdateSite/
```

and

```
eclipsec -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -source http://www.sconsolidator.com/update -destination file:C:/SConsUpdateSite/
```

Alternatively you can download following 7 files into a directory with the two subdirectories *features* and *plugins*:

- [features/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.depviz.feature_1.0.0.201707140647.jar](http://www.sconsolidator.com/update/features/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.depviz.feature_1.0.0.201707140647.jar)
- [features/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.feature_1.0.0.201707140647.jar](http://www.sconsolidator.com/update/features/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.feature_1.0.0.201707140647.jar)
- [plugins/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.core_1.0.0.201707140647.jar](http://www.sconsolidator.com/update/plugins/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.core_1.0.0.201707140647.jar)
- [plugins/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.depviz_1.0.0.201707140647.jar](http://www.sconsolidator.com/update/plugins/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.depviz_1.0.0.201707140647.jar)
- [plugins/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.help_1.0.0.201707140647.jar](http://www.sconsolidator.com/update/plugins/ch.hsr.ifs.sconsolidator.help_1.0.0.201707140647.jar)
- [artifacts.jar](http://www.sconsolidator.com/update/artifacts.jar)
- [content.jar](http://www.sconsolidator.com/update/content.jar)

Comment: Hi, thanks! I'm trying to do as you suggested, but I only have installed on the offline Linux machine, and don't have any of the Eclipse resources to run these commands on my online Windows machine

Comment: You can also directly download the 7 files (see my edited answer above)